# Detect if a swipe is from the left edge of the screen

Tags: angularjs, swipe

I'm currently using `ngSwipeRight` to detect right swipes and show a sidebar.  To more closely mimic the behaviour of mobile applications I'd like to only show the sidebar if the user swipes inwards from the left edge of the screen.

My understanding is that this is not possible using `ngSwipeRight`, although I have found mention of the `$swipe` service, which may be able to help.  Unfortunatley though, [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch/service/$swipe) for this seems to be sorely lacking!

I can successfully include the `$swipe` service in my controller, but how can I use it to detect if the user actually swipes from the very left edge of the screen?

```
app.controller('bodyCtrl', ['$scope', '$swipe', function($scope, $swipe){

    $scope.maybeShowSidebar = function(){
        if( { swipe is from left edge of screen } )
            $scope.showSidebar();
    };

)]};
```